# get the id from url and use it to get a specific data from a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am doing a project for my studies. How can I get the id from the URL and pass it to the controller to get specific data from the table

This some of codes I have tried 
I am now getting this error Couldn't find Major without an ID

Controller:

```rb
class MajorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_major, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /majors
  # GET /majors.json
  def index
    @majors = Major.all
  end

  # GET /majors/1
  # GET /majors/1.json
  def show
    @majors = Major.find(params[:major_id])
    @courses = Course.all
  end
```

These are my routes

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
  get 'home/contactUs'
  resources :courses
  resources :majors
  resources :sciences
  get '/majors/:id', to: 'majors#show', as: 'Major'
  root 'home#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Show

```rb
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @major.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @major.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Science:</strong>
  <%= @major.science.name %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Number of courses:</strong>
  <%= @major.courses.count %>
</p>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

  <% @major.course.each do |m| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= m.name %></td>
      <td><%= m.description %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_major_path(@major) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', majors_path %>
```

i expect the output is the only two courses i have but it output them all

Comment: This thing is explained in the very beginning of the rails routing guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov done it but now i am having this issue "Couldn't find Major without an ID"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by adding the route as @KonstantinStrukov said 
edited the show

```rb
  <% @major.courses.each do |m| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= m.name %></td>
      <td><%= m.description %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Rotes file

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
  get 'home/contactUs'
  resources :courses
  resources :majors
  resources :sciences
  get '/majors/:id', to: 'majors#show', as: 'Major'
  root 'home#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Controller

```rb
  def show
    @majors = Major.where(params[:id])
    @courses = Course.all
  end
```